# How to calculate the running balance of an asset based on INPUT and OUTPUT

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at different blockchain transactions and wanted to create a running balance of a given asset based on `INPUT_ADDRESS` (the address sending the currency) `INPUT_AMOUNT` (the amount being sent by an INPUT_ADDRESS), `OUTPUT_ADDRESS` (the address receiving the currency) and `OUTPUT_AMOUNT` (the amount being received by an OUTPUT_ADDRESS)

Here's a sample of a table I'm using:

```
BLOCK_DATE | BLOCK_HEIGHT | TRANS_HASH | INPUT_ADDRESS | OUTPUT_ADDRESS | INPUT_AMOUNT | OUTPUT_AMOUNT
01/11/2020    190            15c7853       abc             xyz1             -0.01          0.0001
01/11/2020    190            14v9876       abc             xyz2             -0.50          0.70
01/11/2020    191            19vc842       abc             xyz3             -5.03          0.413
01/12/2020    192            20ff4d3       abc             xyz4             -0.06          0.201
01/12/2020    192            154gf34       xyz1            abc              -0.07          0.18
01/12/2020    192            45f4ti5       ggg             abc              -0.10          0.24
01/12/2020    192            33cv5c5       jjj             abc              -0.08          1.13
```

If I were to calculate a running sum of address `abc`, what's an efficient way of going about this? I tried using something like:

```
SELECT BLOCK_DATE, BLOCK_HEIGHT, TRANS_HASH, INPUT_ADDRESS, OUTPUT_ADDRESS, INPUT_AMOUNT, OUTPUT_AMOUNT, SUM (INPUT_AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS RunningAgeTotal
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE
WHERE INPUT_ADDRESS = abc
```

In this particular example, the total balance for abc would be the sum of OUTPUT_AMOUNT where abc is the OUTPUT_ADDRESS (i.e 0.18 + 0.24 + 1.13) + the sum of INPUT_AMOUNT where abc is the INPUT_ADDRESS (i.e. -0.01 + -0.50 + -5.03 + -0.06). So, 1.55 + (-5.60) = **-4.05**

But I don't think this is the right way of going about this and I'm not sure how to account for the OUTPUT_AMOUNT (e.g. when abc receives is an OUTPUT_ADDRESS and receives an OUTPUT_AMOUNT)

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.   Can you explain why the rows have different amounts?  I would expect only one amount.

Comment: Sure, edited. And the rows have different amounts because there could be fees associated with the transaction or it could be split into different transactions. I don't need to focus on those aspects right now, though

Comment: Running totals at the row level require one or more columns that define the ordering and are unique per row.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when input_address = 'ABC' then input_amount
                when output_address = 'ABC' then output_amount
           end) over (order by block_date) as running_amount
from transaction_table t
where 'ABC' in (input_address, output_address);
```

This is a cumulative sum of the amounts aligned with the input/output columns.

EDIT:

You may want:

```
       sum(case when input_address = 'ABC' then input_amount
                when output_address = 'ABC' then output_amount
           end) over (order by block_date, block_height) as running_amount
```

Comment: This gives me the overall total balance but I was looking for a rolling balance (i.e. each row would return the most recent `running_amount`, not the final total)

Comment: @David . . . This is a running balance between days.  To get a running balance *within* a single day, you need a column that specifies the ordering within a day.  That ordering is not clear from your question.

Comment: `block_height` could specify the ordering (i.e. the lower the number, the older the transaction). would I need to use that in an ORDER_BY in some way? sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: @David . . . You would add that to the `ORDER BY` but it has duplicates in your sample data.

Comment: I tried this and it appears to work correctly in terms of the running total on a per block_height basis, however it doesn't limit to just that `input_address ='ABC'` and instead returns every row: 

`select t.*, sum(case when input_address = 'ABC' then input_amount when output_address = 'ABC' then output_amount end) over (order by block_height) as running_amount from transaction_table t`